# Stuck on 800x600 resolution

Tags: drivers, 18.04, display-resolution

Yesterday I installed 18.04 LTS and everything was fine, until I rebooted laptop after installation and relized I'm stuck at 800x600 resolution and that I can't change it. I googled and read literally every solution on google I could find but nothing helped ( xrandr, xorg, grub etc...)

I'm using Asus vivobookX512DK with AMD Ryzen 5 3500U, could it be It's not compatible with linux? Is that even posibble?

Will installing older version maybe help because there's more compatibility?
I mean I know it's problem with drivers, but I dont know how to solve it

Comment: For newer hardware install newer,  not older.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by updating to 19.04.

Here's how I did it.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-19-04-disco-dingo

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please include essential parts of the answer here.